# Kiwi tests are not working in xcode 7

Tags: unit-testing, ios9, xcode7, kiwi

I have this code in my xcode7 project:

```
SPEC_BEGIN(TTests)

describe(@"Math", ^{
    it(@"is pretty cool", ^{
        [[theValue(1) should] equal:theValue(1)];
    });
});
SPEC_END
```

and I have this error when I run this test:
 -[TTests Math_IsPrettyCool] failed: 'Math, is pretty cool' [FAILED], Invalid parameter not satisfying： !stayUp || CLClientIsBackgroundable(internal->fClient)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out that I had this code in my project:

```
CLLocationManager *manager = [CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
```

when I removed this code kiwi tests stated to work fine.